# What does 'Distance flown' actually mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's a distance climbed and a distance fallen, so it can't be those..and it wouldn't be actual flying since they are mods.

Comment: I think it has to do with free-falling minecarts, but I'd have to try that to be sure.

Comment: @badp Can't be; I have 3km of whatever it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [mineraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Statistics):

> Distance traveled upwards and forwards at the same time, while more than one block above the ground.

Comment: so... roughly how many times that you've jumped off of cliffs?

Comment: By the sounds of it, jumping any distance or falling off small ledges..not really flying.

Comment: This could be there for future expansion involving catapults of some type (or pistons that act in awesome ways)

Comment: It's not a stat for *you*, silly. It's a stat to help Creepers track how far they've thrown you with their explosions.

Comment: I believe the stat refers to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSaGG0CmEfQ) kind of thing.

Comment: @SevenSideDie that should be posted as an answer, I think.